# issues whenn trying to return in c

Tags: c

I have to write a code for the c language for class but I'm getting this errors because the code is not returning the value correctly for some reason that I don't understand at all.

Requirements:

Tickets for the amusement park for the day cost $30.00 per adult, and $12.00 per child. There is also a 10% discount if more than 10 tickets are ordered in total.

Given two integer variables, num_adults, and num_children, calculate the total cost for amusement park admission for the day and store it in double variable total_cost.

my code: (you can assume every variable has been properly initialized. )

```
if (num_adults + num_children > 10)
{
    total_cost =((30.00 * num_adults) + (12.00 * num_children)) - (0.10 * ((30.00 * num_adults) + (12.00 * num_children)));
    printf("%d\n", total_cost);

}
else 
{
   total_cost=((30.00 * num_adults) + (12.00 * num_children));
   printf("%d\n", total_cost);
}
```

Comment: What error(s) ?

Comment: returning from where?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Since `total_cost` is a double, you don't use `%d` to print it.  If your compiler isn't warning you, turn up the warnings, or get a better compiler.

Comment: Why not calculate the cost without discount.  Then if the number of tickets is more than 10, apply a 10% discount.  That saves repetition — and there's a lot of repetition in your code.  If the cost of an adult ticket changes to $32.00, you have to edit 3 places, not just one.  That's bad.

Comment: When you say "return", do you actually mean "print"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best guess: You want to output it not as an integer (%d) but as a float %f

so do this:

```
printf("%.2f\n", total_cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int total_tickets(int c, int a)
{
  return (c + a);
}

float total_cost(int c, int a)
{
  return ((12.00 * c) + (30.00 * a));
}

float discounted_cost(int c, int a)
{
  return (total_cost(c, a) * 0.9);
}

float actual_cost(int c, int a)
{
  if(total_tickets(c, a) < 10)
  {
    return (total_cost(c, a));
  }
  else
  {
    return (discounted_cost(c, a));
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int c, a;

  c = 2; a = 2;
  printf("%.2f\n", actual_cost(c, a));

  c = 5; a = 5;
  printf("%.2f\n", actual_cost(c, a));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have a bug — take care to branch the right way on equality. You're giving out discounts on 10 tickets, not just "more than 10 tickets".  I'm not a great one for long names, but even I draw the line at `a` and `c` rather than `adult` and `child`, or `n_adult` and `n_child`, or thereabouts. I wouldn't use `float` — you should use `double`. I'd probably organize the tests slightly differently (calling `total_cost()` something like `list_price()`, and then `actual_cost()` might have `double cost = list_price(n_adult, n_child); if ((n_adult + n_child) > 10) cost *= 0.9; return cost;`.